# Python selenium select a dynamic button

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I was trying to slect a button but I failed doing so by many ways.
The source code look like this:

```
<div class="sc-fzXfPJ soOmg">
<button type="submit" class="sc-fzXfQu KbRNP SuiButton SuiButton--primary 
   SuiButton--wide">
      <div class="SuiButton-content">
          <div class="SuiButton-label">
               <span class="sc-fzXfNh cnQLcv">
                    <p>LET'S GET IT!</p>
```

When I try xpath it gave me:

```python
/html/body/div[11]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/button
```

and when I run:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[11]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/button').click()
```

It returns an error. The button text is: LET'S GET IT!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you show us the url of your page?

Comment: driver.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[11]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/button').click()

try this if that can help.

Comment: the link is here:https://airjordanretro1highsatinredwom.splashthat.com/ , I try chropath and the xpath is still not working for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having said that using absolute xpath is not a good practice.

Try some alternatives:

Using CSS selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
```

Using Xpath selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

OR using button text which is not possible by CSS selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(.,"LET\'S GET IT!")]').click()
```

To avoid unnecessary timeout and maintain synchronization in your scripts use Explicit wait as mentioned below:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
```

Import following package for that:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bad idea to use absolute XPath for this, since they are very fragile. Try ChroPath extension and find relative XPath, this should fix problem.

Sometimes it abuses values inside so you may want to remove text from element to get relative XPath without relying on value.

Comment: thanks for helping, but I use ChroPath and the xpath it gives me is still not workig

Answer (score 0):

This would help

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(),'S GET IT!')]").click()
```

Comment: I tried this,and it still gives me error.thanks for helping

Comment: What error it is?  Can you paste the error message here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Xpath` with its axes. To learn more about axes you can [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp).

For your resolution, you can use this `Xpath` -

`//p[contains(text(),"GET IT"]/ancestor::button[@type='submit']`.

Using absolute `Xpath` is not a good idea as it is easily breakable and should not be preferred.

Let me know if you face any issues, the resolution is given on the basis of code you have shared.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, I update the url I am running.This xpath still not works.